# Page jumps in ipad on hide of the search bar with skrollr

Tags: ipad, skrollr, searchbar

i am new skrollr i want disable the skrollr in mobile device width which is less than 768px i am using   $(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);

```
function resizeWindow(){
var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(newWindowWidth <= 769){             
        skrollr.init().destroy();
    } else{
        var s = skrollr.init();
    }
}
```

it works fine for me the issue is when i open in ipad or iphone when the search bar hides the page jumps to start point.i tired using
   "meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" "
 in header also and it still i am have the same issue . any help is appreciated